# Calling git diff on a specific direcotry with libgit2

Tags: c++, git, git-diff, libgit2

Calling git diff with a specific directory is pretty straightforward on the cmd but I need to call it from a c++ program. I am a bit confused with all the different diff functions libgit2 provides but with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752123/how-to-print-diff-files-in-libgit2) question, I got it to work by showing results for the whole repo. For a specific path I tried using `git_index_get_bypath` but it always fails with an abort message.

```
git_index_get_bypath(index, "path/of/the/directory/inside/repo", GIT_INDEX_STAGE_NORMAL);
```

Also every time I change the repo path to a more specific directory inside it, it crashes with an assertion failure and an abort message, which makes sense.

I call `git_diff_index_to_index(&diff, repo, NULL, index, &diffopts);` to get the differences with `diffopts.flags = GIT_DIFF_FORMAT_NAME_ONLY;`

---

**UPDATE**

```
git_repository *repo = NULL;
git_index *index = NULL;
git_diff *diff;
git_diff_options diffopts;

const char * REPO_PATH = "path/to/repo/"; 
//tried to be more specific with .../repo/.git but its the same thing
char *DIR_PATH = "path/to/repo/specific/dir"; 

git_repository_open(&repo, REPO_PATH);

diffopts = GIT_DIFF_OPTIONS_INIT;
diffopts.flags = GIT_DIFF_FORMAT_NAME_ONLY;

//diffopts.pathspec.count = 1;
//diffopts.pathspec.strings = &DIR_PATH;

git_repository_index(&index, repo);

git_diff_index_to_workdir(&diff, repo, index, &diffopts);

size_t num_deltas = git_diff_num_deltas(diff);

//do stuff with diff
```

Uncommenting

```
diffopts.pathspec.count = 1;
diffopts.pathspec.strings = &DIR_PATH;
```

`git_diff_num_deltas` returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most paths handled by the library, they're usually relative to the root of the repository (with a few caveats, hopefully fixable with a bit of documentation).

In your example, you are passing absolute paths to both the repo (per the documentation) and your interesting pathspecs. Expectedly, no files show up when diffing, because the path are munged together behind-the-scene.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the `diff` to a particular folder, then set the `pathspec` of the diff options to the paths that you're interested in.

For example:

```
char *path = "path/of/the/directory/inside/repo";
diffopts.pathspec.count = 1;
diffopts.pathspec.strings = &path;
git_diff_index_to_index(&diff, repo, NULL, index, &diffopts);
```

Comment: Whenever I uncomment the `pathspec` related code the diff returns nothing. I will update my question with the code for more clarity

Comment: @Segmentation It's not obvious, but the pathspec must be relative to the root of the repository. Your question uses an absolute one, which will never match, and should instead use "specific/dir". HTH !

Comment: @tiennou yes, that worked. Please answer it so i can accept as solution.